# Insert String into specific position in INI-style-file

Tags: php

I have got a file which is looking like this:

```
[TestKey1]
Test1
Test2

[TestKey2]
Item1
Item2
```

Now, I want to add another key (e.g. Test3). This is my code.

```
$ModulCat = "TestKey1";
$ModulName = "Test-Update";

$ModulList = '../cake.inc';
$ModulListAsFile = file('../cake.inc');

$line_number = false;   
$fHandler = fopen($ModulList, 'r+');

if($fHandler)
{
    while (list($key, $line) = each($ModulListAsFile) and !$line_number) 
    {
        $line_number = (strpos($line, $ModulCat) !== FALSE) ? $key + 1 : $line_number;
    }

    if($line_number)
        echo "$line_number\n";
    else
        echo "Not found";

    GoToLine($fHandler, $line_number + 1);

    fwrite($fHandler, "\x8\n$ModulName");
    fclose($fHandler);
}
else
{
    echo 'Can not open file.';
}

function GoToLine($handle,$line)
{
  fseek($handle,0);
  $i = 0;
  $bufcarac = 0;                    

  for($i = 1;$i<$line;$i++)
  {
    $ligne = fgets($handle);
    $bufcarac += strlen($ligne);
  }  

  fseek($handle,$bufcarac);
}
```

But this changes my file to this:

```
Test1
Test2
Test-Update

[TestKey2]
Item1
Item2
```

So my first line gets totally removed, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I've got this code now:

```
$file = new SplFileObject($ModulList, "r+");

while(!$file->eof())
{
    $line = $file->fgets();
    if (strpos($line, "[$ModulCat]") !== false)
    {
        echo "Category found.";
        $file->fwrite("$ModulName\n");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Category not found.";
    }
}
```

Which changes this:

```
[Stammdaten]
Test-KIA

[System]
Updates
UpdateItem
```

to this:

```
[Stammdaten]
Test-Update
ystem]
Updates
UpdateItem
```

Why does it remove one item and one character in the next line?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Whats wrong with using a built in system, such as xml, json or ini?

Comment: The menu bar on my webpage is build using this. It goes through all files and adds the menus. [Item] would be the Menu Title while Test1 is a menu item.

Comment: Please add you `GoToLine` function as well.

Comment: Sure, but why save it in this way, when you could save it with a naitive format, and make your life 10x easier?

Comment: My task is to make it like this.

Comment: I’d suggest you use `parse_ini_file` for reading, manipulate the data – and then write it back using one of the functions you find in the user comments on the manual page for the aforementioned function …

Comment: Tried another method, please check the first post.